# Why does jQuery .one function only work when scrolling down?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following function to start an animation when an element is in viewport. The animation should start if 1) the element is already in view on page load, or 2) by scrolling to the element for the first time.

This code works, except the scroll function only works when scrolling **down** to the element. If I load the page *below* the element, and scroll **up**, the animation does not start:

```
$(window).on("load", myanimation);

$(window).one("scroll", myanimation); // this only works on downward scroll
```

This is how I'm checking if the element is visible:

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function () {
    let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    let viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};
```

And this is my function:

```
function myanimation(e){

    if ($('#welcome').isInViewport()) {  
        console.log('In view.')
    } else {
        console.log('Not in view.')
    }
};
```

I only want the animation to perform on the first scroll only, so that's why I'm using `.one`.

How can I make the animation start from either direction?

Comment: Welll, `one` will fire the callback once and then destroy itself. When you start off you can *only* scroll down on a page, so logically it's impossible to scroll up with the `one` callback attached since you would have had to scroll down first which destroys the event listener.

Comment: Have you tried console logging something inside your `.one()` function to see if it's immediately fired when the page loads in those cases where you're loading the page below the element? That probably only happens b/c the browser is setting your scroll position for you to remember your spot on the page, so maybe that is firing the function at that point, before you have a chance to scroll up.

Comment: @VLAZ, when you refresh a page, it reloads it at the same place you were which may be below the element, requiring your first scroll to be an UP (or if you load the page with an anchor link that's below the element). Shouldn't the "one" callback work on the first scroll, even if that scroll is up?

Comment: @cj750, yes the console log functions I show in my code above are inside the one function. I turned off the on.load function so I could isolate just the scroll, and no, it does not log anything when I load the page below the element. Nor does it log anything as I scroll up. It only logs it if I start above the element and scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is solution for your problem.

```
var once = false;
$(window).on("load", myAnim);
$(window).one("scroll", scollTopCheck);

$.fn.isInViewport = function () {

    let elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    let elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    let viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    let viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
};

function scollTopCheck(){

    if($(window).scrollTop()>0 && !once){
        once = true;
        $(window).one("scroll", myAnim);
    }else{
        myAnim();  
    }
};

function myAnim(){
    if ($('#welcome').isInViewport()) {  
        console.log('In view.')
    } else {
        console.log('Not in view.')
    }
}
```